# User Profile Photo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, path, multer

I have made a login and register system. But there is a problem about user profile photo. If user doesnt want to add profile photo then that user's profile photo will be null. But I get an error.

**this is my profile part of my user.js**

```
profile:{
type: String,
}
```

**And this is the related post route of my register.**

```
let user= new User({
username: req.body.username,
email: req.body.email,
password: hashedPassword,
profile: req.file.path.replace(/^public/, '')
});
```

**And lastly this is my register.pug:**

```
.file-field.input-field(method="post")
.btn.grey
label Profile Photo
input(name='profile', type='file', enctype="multipart/form-data")
```

But when I do submit without selecting any profile photo it gives the error below:

> (node:26436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'path' of undefined

But why it is happening? I have already decleared profile photo as unrequired. So why that it searches for path if I do not want to upload profile photo?

Comment: What does `console.log(req.file)` returns in the post route?

Comment: It shows the image data

Comment: originalname: '7bf414542724fe2e7186e1d5194cb29f.jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'public/uploads',
  filename: '7bf414542724fe2e7186e1d5194cb29f.jpeg',                                                  
  path: 'public\\uploads\\7bf414542724fe2e7186e1d5194cb29f.jpeg',                                         
  size: 23205 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could verify if there's a req.file before setting it on the user object , and in case there's not , set it as a empty string

```
let user= new User({
username: req.body.username,
email: req.body.email,
password: hashedPassword,
profile: req.file ? req.file.path.replace(/^public/, '') : ""
});
```

Comment: yes it worked. But can you tell me how it works? Like what does it mean?

Comment: it's called ternary operator and works like this , you pass a condition , if that condition is true , it will take the code that is after the ? , if the condition is false it take the code that is after the : , since null it's a falsy value , when req.file it's null it will take the code after the :